# How to switch streams win ExoPlayer using animations

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` as the my video component and would like to initialise the player with several streams (some local some network) and programatically switch between streams with a transition that makes the old stream collapse to bottom and new stream stretch from above all while continue playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have media codec which support all kind of stream.

```
val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
```